# extracting a youtube URL from a string

Tags: php

What I've tried so far is this function:

```
function isYoutubeUrl($url) {
    return preg_match("#^https?://(?:www\.)?youtube.com#", $url);
}
```

But it's only working with a plain youtube string like that:

```
$string = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJIXm6U4df';
$newString = isYoutubeURL($string);
if($newString); // true
```

I need a function which checks a string for a youtube URL and if there is one, return the url.

```
$string = 'this is so crazy...http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJIXm6U4df';
$newString = extractYoutubeUrl($string);
echo $newString; // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJIXm6U4df
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^ - checks from the begining of the string -  remove it and try

return preg_match("#https?://(?:www.)?youtube.com#", $url);

this will be your function :

```
function extractYoutubeUrl($url) {
    return preg_match("#https?://(?:www\.)?youtube.com#", $url);
}
```

Comment: what about the link youtu.be ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function extractYoutubeUrl($url) {
  if(preg_match("#(http://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=[%&=#\w-]*)#", $url, $result))
    return $result[0];
  return null;
}
```